# why java.util.Set can't return any value?

Tags: java, set

`java.util.Set` specifies only methods that return all records (via Iterator or array).

Why is there no option to return *any* value from Set?

It has a lot of sense in the real life. For example, I have a bowl of strawberries and I want to take just one of them.  I totally don't care which one.

Why I can't do the same in java?

Comment: You can do it in java, just not with a Set. Or you could do `set.iterator().next()`

Comment: Do you want a solution or the answer to "WHY?"

Comment: Thx, it is true. But I need Set uniquness and also don't want to use lists with their's strict order, because logically bowl of straberries is a set. "set.iterator().next()" looks too verbose for such a small need (getAny).

Comment: wuppi - great question, sorry that didn't mention. I need the answer "why" rather than solution "how to do this".

Comment: What makes sense in real life must not necessarily make sense on(in) a computer. The bowl in real life is not a set but (more or less) a bag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not answerable.  You'd have to ask the original designers of the Java collections framework.

One plausible reason is that methods with non-deterministic behavior tend to be problematic:

- They make unit testing harder.
- They make bugs harder to track down.
- They are more easily misunderstood and misused by programmers who haven't bothered to read the API documentation.

For hashtable-based set organizations, the behavior a "get some element" method is going to be non-deterministic, or at least *difficult* to determine / predict.

By the way, you can trivially get *some* element of a non-empty set as follows:

```
Object someObject = someSet.iterator().next();
```

Getting a truly (pseudo-)random element is a bit more tricky / expensive because you can't index the elements of a set.  (You need to extract all of the set elements into an array ...)

---

On revisiting this, I realized that there is another reason.  It is simply that `Set` is based on the mathematical notion of a set, and the elements of a set in mathematics have no order.  It is simply meaningless to talk about the first element of a mathematical set.

Comment: obtaining an element from a set doesn't have to be non-deterministic; it can just be undocumented/undefined since you shouldn't really care about that anyways. That's how NSSet in Cocoa/CocoaTouch works on iOS; call the anyObject method to just get any object. it could be the same each time or it could be different; there's nothing in the docs telling you what happens so the behavior is free to change.

Comment: @Kevlar - *" ... since you shouldn't really care about that anyways"*.  Unfortunately, many people are likely to write incorrect code that does depend on it.  People are stupid like that.  I posit that the reason the API was designed with no `first()` is ... in part ... to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

A `java.util.Set` is an unordered collection; you can see it as a bag that contains things, but not in any particular order. It would not make sense to have a `get(int index)` method, because elements in a set don't have an index.

The designers of the standard Java library didn't include a method to get a random element from a `Set`. If you want to know why, that's something you can only speculate about. Maybe they didn't think it was necessary, or maybe they didn't even think about it.

It's easy to write a method yourself that gets a random element out of a `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the index of the elements, try using Queue instead of Set.

```
    Queue q = new ArrayDeque();
    q.element(); // retrieves the first object but doesn't remove
    q.poll(); // retrieves and removes first object
```

Answer (score 1):

While a plain Set is in no particular, SortedSet and NavigableSet provide a guaranteed order and methods which support this. You can use [first()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#first%28%29) and [last()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#last%28%29)

```
SortedSet<E> set = ...
E e1 = set.first(); // a value
E e2 = set.last(); // also a value.
```

Comment: A Set doesn't guarantee order, but it's not "unordered by definition". SortSet is a Set and yet it's ordered.

Comment: @SteveKuo Good point. Sets in mathematics are unordered. In Java, a plain Set is described as being "in no particular order"

Answer (score 0):

Actually the iterator is a lot better then using get(position) (which is something you can do on a `java.util.List`). It allows for collection modifications during the iterations for one thing. The reason you don't have them in sets is probably because most of them don't guarantee order of insertion. You can always do something like `new ArrayList<?>(mySet).get(position)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned with performance you can create a new type and back the data in an arraylist.

( Please note before donwvoting this is just an naive implementation of the idea and not the proposed final solution )

```
import ...

public class PickableSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E>{

    private final List<E> arrayList = new ArrayList<E>();
    private final Set<E>  hashSet   = new HashSet<E>();
    private final Random  random    = new Random();

    public boolean add( E e ) {
        return hashSet.add( e ) && arrayList.add( e );
    }
    public int size() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return hashSet.iterator();
    }

    public E pickOne() {
        return arrayList.get( random.nextInt( arrayList.size() ) );
    }
}
```

Of course, since you're using a different interface you'll have to cast to invoke the method:

```
Set<String> set = new PickableSet<String>();
set.add("one");
set.add("other");
String oneOfThem = ((PickableSet)set).pickOne();
```

ie 
https://gist.github.com/1986763

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can with a little bit of work like this

```
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    Random r = new Random();
    String res = s.toArray(new String[0])[r.nextInt(s.toArray().length)];
```

This grabs a randomly selected object from the set.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd guess it's because your solution doesn't really return a single value from the Set - it grabs _all_ the values into an array (twice), then takes one from there. So it doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: Nothing was said about efficiency.